# How to return value inestead promise in this function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await, return

I'm trying to make the connection with MongoDB database but I can't to export database object, inestead export a promise.

What I would be missing?

> index.js

```
export const db = async() => { 
  return await MongoClient.connect(MONGO_URL)
}
```

I have also tried this way:

```
export const db = async() => { 
  const result = await MongoClient.connect(MONGO_URL)
  return result
}
```

> resolvers.js

```
import { db } from '/mongodb'
```

This function returns Async Function db

Comment: I have also tried this way:

    `export const db = async() => { 
      const result = await MongoClient.connect(MONGO_URL)
      return result
    }`

Comment: `What I would be missing?` time. you can not return/export a value that does not exist (yet). That's what Promises are/are dealing with; a value that will be available at some point in the future, but not yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
const db = async() => { 
  return await MongoClient.connect(MONGO_URL)
}

export const dbResult=db()
```

Then

```
import { dbResult} from './mongodb'
dbResult.then(res=>{
     //see what they are
     //console.log(dbResult,res)
})
```

Comment: `const Posts = dbResult.collection('messages')`

Returns `dbResult.collection is not a function`

Comment: @AlejandroUray ??

Comment: @AlejandroUray,updated, try again, `dbResult` is a `promise`, you can't call it directly, see the console.

Comment: you can simplify this to `export const dbResult = MongoClient.connect(MONGO_URL);`

Comment: @Thomas, that's because I don't know `MongoClient`. I just know `promise` and `async`.

Comment: Thanks @xianshenglu I solved!

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you are exporting an async function (promise). What you could do is:

1) Change to `require()` over `import` (generally better, ES6 modules is iffy)

2) Do something like `const database = await (require('./mongodb').db())`